# Program runs well in Visual Studio but not from outside

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-c++, profiling

I have encountered a very weird situation:
I have developped a rich WPF client in C# for a client of mine. It performs well on all our developer machines but poor on my client's computers (in some respect - see below).

Well the weird thing is:
If have set up a virtual machine for testing. When I start my app from the explorer or the console the app performs poorly. But when I start the same app within visual studio 2017 it performs well! There is no noticable difference between debug and release. Also "start without debugger" performs well.

I not see any bottleneck during tests: not much CPU usage, not much DISK IO, not much network IO, not too much memory consumption. Noticable is when my application is lagging that the state in the windows 10 task manager changes from "beeing executed" to "inactive".

I am using WPF, C#, Oracle Database (via .NET Native). There are several mask my client has problems with but I am currently debugging one dialog which has 7 lines (read from the database) times 26 textboxes with databinding. The problem occurs when I change the data displayed. It seems to be lagging when the the Datacontext of the line (panel) is changed to the new loaded object.

I am grateful for any hints of what might happen oder how I investigate that any further.

Edits:
- described the actual problem in more details

Comment: "in some respect" It would be very useful to know in *which* respect the app is performing poorly.

Comment: "poorly" = slow? it will be waiting for some out-of-process task to complete. that can be anything. you will need to narrow it down to a minimal piece of code. do you use: tcp/ip sockets, named pipes, database connections, GDI+, WMI, LDAP, ....?

Comment: This is what profilers are for. If the performance issues only come up in some specific environments, use a tool like [PerfView](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/releases) that can be run without installation. There is a [series of videos](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial) by the author covering both basic topics like CPU time analysis and advanced topics like blocked time analysis. I have no idea how well it works for .NET Native but supposedly it can even analyze .NET core apps running on linux.